# AppleScript to guess notes app password

Tags: applescript, password, notes.app

I accidentally set a password on my notes app and I have no idea what it could be. I was hoping to write some code to just brute force guess at it using AppleScript.

I really don’t have a ton of knowledge of how to do this - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Something like:

```
tell application Notes

select specific note

For loop over passwords

Try password

Break if works
```

Comment: Why don't you reset the Notes password rather than trying to break it? Are you using a Mac or an iPhone/iPad?

Comment: My understanding is if you reset the notes you can’t access an already locked note. They’re on iCloud so it’s on both phone/mac